# opp_runall -q runnumbers returned nonzero exit status omnet++

Tags: command-line, omnet++

I try to run the simulation from command line with the following command, 
`$ opp_runall -j2 ./inetmanet-3.x-mactest2 -u Cmdenv -c General -r 1 -n ../..:../../../src:../../../tutorials --image-path=../../../images -l ../../../src/INET omnetpp.ini`

I get a weird error, which does not make sense to me, any one can help as follows.

`what():  ASSERT: Condition '(int)signalListenerCount.size() == lastSignalID+1' does not hold in function registerSignal, ccomponent.cc line 414 opp_runall: ./inetmanet-3.x-mactest2 [...] -q runnumbers returned nonzero exit status`

I using omnetpp RC2 latest release, 1992-2017.

any help?

Comment: I think you have a bug in your simulation. It could be that something inside your code is incompatible with changes in 5.1-RC2. I wouldn't recommend using release candidate versions for experiments anyway -- they're intended as just that, candidates for release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same problem. It is actually a bug/feature in newer versions of OMNeT++, where the signal handling was improved. I just discussed this problem with Attila Török on the mailing list.

This occurs if a signal is registered in an external library during static initialization. Three possible solutions:

1. Citing Attila:
   Insert `EXECUTE_ON_STARTUP(cComponent::clearSignalState());` into `ccomponent.cc`, right after the definition of `cComponent::signalListenerCount`, then rebuilding OMNeT++.
2. Move your signal registration out of the static initialization phase. This might or might not be possible in your scenario, but avoids modifications of OMNeT++ itself.
3. Downgrade OMNeT++ and wait until this is fixed upstream. At least 5.0 works.

Comment: The recommended solution is definitely 2. It has some speed advantages and I see no reason why that would not be possible in any project.

Comment: I agree with @Rudi, but the next OMNeT++ release will include the 1. fix, so it will work, even though it is not the best way.